# Deadlock occuring in the Dining Philosophers code

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

Here's my implementation of the Philosopher dinner concurrence problem:
5 philosophers where each one extends Thread:

the problem is everytime the program finish inside a deadlock. I tried different solutions but no one fixed the problem.
maybe someone can give me an help.

this is my program:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

class Fork {
    public static final char FORK = '|';
    public static final char NO_FORK = ' ';
    int id;

    public Fork(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Philosopher extends Thread {
    public static final char PHIL_THINKING = '-';
    public static final char PHIL_LEFT_FORK = '=';
    public static final char PHIL_EATING = 'o';
    private final int id;

    public Philosopher(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final int tableOffset = 4 * id;
        final Object leftLock = S5Philosophers.listOfLocks[id];
        final Object rightLock = S5Philosophers.listOfLocks[(id + 1)
                % S5Philosophers.NUM_PHILOSOPHERS];
        final int table__farL = tableOffset + 0;
        final int table__left = tableOffset + 1;
        final int table_philo = tableOffset + 2;
        final int table_right = tableOffset + 3;
        final int table__farR = (tableOffset + 4)
                % (4 * S5Philosophers.NUM_PHILOSOPHERS);

        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(S5Philosophers.UNIT_OF_TIME
                        * (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(6)));
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
            // Try to get the chopstick on the left
            synchronized (leftLock) {
                synchronized (S5Philosophers.class) {
                    S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table__farL] = Fork.NO_FORK;
                    S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table__left] = Fork.FORK;
                    S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table_philo] = PHIL_LEFT_FORK;
                }

                try {
                    sleep(S5Philosophers.UNIT_OF_TIME * 1);
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
                // Try to get the chopstick on the right
                synchronized (rightLock) {
                    synchronized (S5Philosophers.class) {
                        S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table_philo] = PHIL_EATING;
                        S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table_right] = Fork.FORK;
                        S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table__farR] = Fork.NO_FORK;
                        //notify();
                    }
                    try {
                        sleep(S5Philosophers.UNIT_OF_TIME * 1);
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    // Release fork
                    synchronized (S5Philosophers.class) {
                        S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table__farL] = Fork.FORK;
                        S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table__left] = Fork.NO_FORK;
                        S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table_philo] = PHIL_THINKING;
                        S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table_right] = Fork.NO_FORK;
                        S5Philosophers.dinerTable[table__farR] = Fork.FORK;
                        //notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class S5Philosophers {
    public static final int NUM_PHILOSOPHERS = 5;
    public static final int UNIT_OF_TIME = 50;
    public static final Fork[] listOfLocks = new Fork[NUM_PHILOSOPHERS];
    public static char[] dinerTable = null;

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSOPHERS; i++)
            listOfLocks[i] = new Fork(i);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] a) {
        final char[] lockedDiner = new char[4 * NUM_PHILOSOPHERS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSOPHERS; i++) {
            lockedDiner[4 * i + 0] = Fork.NO_FORK;
            lockedDiner[4 * i + 1] = Fork.FORK;
            lockedDiner[4 * i + 2] = Philosopher.PHIL_LEFT_FORK;
            lockedDiner[4 * i + 3] = Fork.NO_FORK;
        }
        final String lockedString = new String(lockedDiner);

        // safe publication of the initial representation
        synchronized (S5Philosophers.class) {
            dinerTable = new char[4 * NUM_PHILOSOPHERS];
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSOPHERS; i++) {
                dinerTable[4 * i + 0] = Fork.FORK;
                dinerTable[4 * i + 1] = Fork.NO_FORK;
                dinerTable[4 * i + 2] = Philosopher.PHIL_THINKING;
                dinerTable[4 * i + 3] = Fork.NO_FORK;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PHILOSOPHERS; i++) {
            final Thread t = new Philosopher(i);
            // uses this solution to allow terminating the application even if
            // there is a deadlock
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.start();
        }

        System.out.println("The diner table:");
        long step = 0;
        while (true) {
            step++;

            String curTableString = null;
            synchronized (S5Philosophers.class) {
                curTableString = new String(dinerTable);
            }
            System.out.println(curTableString + "   " + step);

            if (lockedString.equals(curTableString))
                break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(UNIT_OF_TIME);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The diner is locked.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented a complete solution for dining philosophers problem.  Now that you have found a solution for your implementation, I wonder if you care to see mine?  I thought it might be fun to whip something together between build and test runs.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is relatively simple:

> 1. Philosopher attempts to get fork on left
>      SUCCEED -> Continue to step 2
>      FAIL -> wait (for a while)
> 2. Philosopher attempts to get fork on right
>      SUCCEED -> Continue to step 3
>      FAIL -> Release left fork and wait (for a while)
> 3. Eat and release both forks.  Then wait (for a while)

The point to emphasize here is that anytime a philosopher fails to get *both* forks, he needs to drop any forks he is holding and wait a bit or deadlock will eventually occur.

Perhaps more importantly, what kind of moron uses two forks to eat?

-- EDIT --

Here is a quick example for the Fork

```
class Fork {
    public static final char FORK = '|';
    public static final char NO_FORK = ' ';
    private int id;
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public Fork(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isHeld() {
        return lock.isLocked();
    }

    // returns true if successfully grabbed!
    public synchronized boolean tryToGrab() {
        return lock.tryLock();
    }

    public void letGo() {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Your idea of using a Semaphore object would work just as well.  Good luck!

Comment: Maybe the point here is to emphasize that you can’t implement a strategy using attempts to lock with `synchronized` as there is no way to *attempt* locking with `synchronized`…

Comment: Right, check to see if fork is available, *then* lock it.  I don't want to write the code for him.  This is clearly an assignment.

Comment: the problem is that if a philosopher take the left fork...and he cannot take the right... he cannot put on the table the left fork...

Comment: Sounds like you know what needs to be fixed.

Comment: i know what i have to fix... the problem is that the philosopher can take all the left fork and so buuum deadlock. the problem is how to fix...

Comment: Holger gave you a huuuge hint.  Don't try to use `synchronized` on the fork.  Check to see if it's available first and *then* reserve it with a `Lock`, or some similar mechanism.

Comment: so could i use a semaphore? the first does an acquire and the second have to wait a release by the first?

Comment: Yup, that is perfectly valid.  As @Holger mentioned in another comment, be sure to synchronize the fork setter methods as well to make them thread-safe.

Comment: Now that I glance back at the code, you don't have any setter methods on the fork anyway...

Comment: I have updated my answer with a quick example of how to use a Lock object.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @jgitter "what kind of moron uses two forks to eat?"  They were chopsticks in the original version.  So the question really is, what kind of moron only sets out one chopstick between each two plates?

Comment: @jgitter if i understand every philosopher need a specific id of the fork right? so i need to have 5 forks where everyone has an id right?

Comment: They don't necessarily need specific ids, though there is nothing wrong with identifying them that way.  What is important is that each fork is uniquely on one philosopher's left and another's right.  How you choose to do that isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is to lock on the *left* fork (or chopstick? Seems you can’t decide…) first. But every philosopher has a different notion of “left fork”. It should be easy to image that it is possible to get into the situation where every philosopher has locked his/her “left fork” in the first step and thus no one can proceed as the “right fork” is locked by the one who sees it as his/her “left fork”.

But you should recognize that situation from your debug output…

---

As a hint how I would solve such a problem: It is possible to represent the entire table state within a single `int` value, assigning each fork one bit. So it would be enough for up to 32 philosophers. Now each philosopher will be initialized with a bitmask telling him/her, which forks (s)he needs. Then a single [atomic update](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet%28int,%20int%29) can be used to allocate both forks/chopsticks at once. So there is no need to deal with single forks then. The allocation may succeed for both or fail leaving the state unchanged. The only thing the philosopher has to remember, besides the invariably assigned fork bits, is whether (s)he currently owns these two forks. After (s)he has finished eating (s)he will put both forks back in a single update as well.

This strategy would solve the deadlock problem but not the theoretically possible starvation of one philosopher (though it is rather unlikely). For my *real life* applications that is not an issue, I never create multi-threaded code that relies on lock fairness.

But if you want to preclude the possibility of starvation entirely you can expand the algorithm described above to a subclass of [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html). This class is an extension to the concept of using an atomic `int` to represent the state and supports *waiting* for the desired resources (bits) to become available. It’s class documentation describes how *fair waiting* can be implemented so no philosopher has to starve…

Comment: i know that, the problem is that i have no idea about to fix

Comment: Do not use the monitor ownership for representing the fork state. You can hold the state in any kind of variable/ data structure, e.g. a single `boolean` can tell whether a fork lies on the table or not. Then use `synchronized` only for performing the thread-safe update to these variables/ data structures.

Comment: @Giovanni Far: I have updated my answer to tell you how I would do it as it differs from the other suggestions. But it’s up to you to decide which way you want to try.

Comment: i reed your answer, thx, about the starvation we don't have fix it... just the problem about the deadlock, but i don't understand how can i solve it with just a boolean variable that explain to me if a philospher has 2 or 0 forks

Comment: @Holger Good suggestions.  If fairness is an issue, the Lock implementations can be configured for fairness.

Comment: In answer to your last question @GiovanniFar, a fork doesn't know if a philosopher has two forks.  That boolean variable would indicate whether that fork is held, but not by whom.  The philosopher knows which ones he is holding and can check to see if a specific fork is held by someone else.  Think OO.

Comment: Glad I could help... if one of these answers helped you, please select it as accepted answer.

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you so much @jgitter with out your help i will never solve it! i'm here from 3pm... to try to solve this homework...

Comment: just kill the synchronized... use ur fork class... check in a while if the lock of a fork is free and wait untill it will be and then lock it. i played in this way: if the id of the philosopher is 0 i ask for the fork 0 for the left... and for the fork 1 for the right. the last philosofer that has id 4 ask for the fork 4 and 0... every time before left and after right

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I have a couple of suggestions:

(1) This is minor, but don't override Thread: Override Runnable.  It's a good habit, but I don't have time to explain why.  Just do it.

```
class Philosopher implements Runnable { ... }
...
Thread t = new Thread(new Philosopher());
```

(2) Don't use `synchronized` for this kind of problem:  Using java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock will give you a lot more flexibility in how you structure your code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

Lock[] listOfLocks = new Lock[NUM_PHILOSOPHERS];
for (int i=0 ; i<listOfLocks.length ; i++) {
    listOfLocks[i] = new ReentrantLock();
}
```

(3) As @Holger has pointed out, you have chosen a strategy that is prone to deadlock; You'll have to try something else.  Unfortunately your strategy is deeply embedded in your code.  That means a lot of re-writing for each new strategy that you try.

Think about how you might isolate the strategy from the rest of the code.  What if you defined a 'Strategy' interface, and what if each of your Philosopher instances used a Strategy to grab the chopsticks.

```
interface Strategy {
    //returns after locking both the leftLock and the rightLock
    public void grabSticks(Lock leftLock, Lock rightLock);
}

class Philosopher implements Runnable {
    private final Strategy strategy;

    public Philosopher(Strategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        while (...) {
            think();
            strategy.grabSticks(leftLock, rightLock);
            eat();
            leftLock.unlock();
            rightLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, each time you want to try something different, you only have to change the grabSticks() method...

...or methods!  There's no reason why each Philosopher has to use the *same* strategy.

Is my Strategy interface good enough?  It's a start anyway, but maybe you could improve on it.  Could it be extended to provide the Philosophers with some more sophisticated way of cooperating than just mutely grabbing the chopsticks?

Good luck, and Have fun!

Comment: I have a suggestion as well, terminology: extend Thread, and implement Runnable ;)

Comment: @KavehGhahremani  Don't extend Thread unless you need to override one of its _other_ methods (i.e., not the run() method).  In nearly all applications, the clean way to start a thread is 'new Thread(new MyRunnable(...)).start();'  Read _Clean Code_ by Robert C. Martin if you want to learn why.